# mount using nfs4 giving no such device error

Tags: filesystems, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount a folder `workspace` from server to the client over nfs. For this I bind the folder to an `/export` by adding the following in my `/etc/fstab` on server:

`/home   /export none    bind`

Then I add the following lines in my `/etc/exports` on my server:

`/export     *(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,fsid=0) 
/export/workspace   *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,nohide)`

I load the exportfs file, and restart the nfs-kernel-server:

`exportfs -vr
service nfs-kernel-server restart`

I now go to my client and check which folders can be exported:

`showmount -e 192.168.145.131
Export list fo 192.168.145.131:
/export/workspace *
/export           *`

But when I try mounting the folder, I get the following error:

`sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.145.131:/workspace nfs/ -v
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sat Apr 19 19:16:51 2014
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.145.131,clientaddr=192.168.145.128'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): No such device
mount.nfs4: No such device`

I have also tried mounting `:/export/workspace` and `:/home/workspace`  but that gives me the same error. I have tried loading the nfs module using modprobe on both client and server, but the module is loaded on both client and server.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if the downVoter would comment why (s)he downVoted the question!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem after 3 days!!

I tried mounting the nfs4 server folder from a client with a newer Kernel version (3.8). I was able to do so. So I copied the configuration file `/boot/configure-3.8-generic` file to my `/usr/src/.config`, and enabled the option `Filesystems -> Network File Systems -> NFS3 client load as module` and `NFS4 client` load as module.

compiled my kernel again, created `initrd image`, updated `grub`, and now I am able to mount the server folder from my 2.6 kernel client also!